# How to use Parse.com with Node/Express and Backbone

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, parse-platform

I have my Todo list set up. I can persist to parse.com with Backbone if I press "Add" button to add a new todo. Only problem is that if i refresh the page, all the todos i just added is gone. Which is correct, because I'm not actually using a backend right now.

When integrating with Node/express, how do I do a post request to parse.com and get back the todos I currently have?

I read in a tutorial to do something like this:

```
var Todos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/todos'
});
```

and something like this:

```
var TodosView = Backbone.View.extend({
  model: todos,
  el: $('.todos-list'), 
  initialize: function() {
    this.model.on('add', this.render, this);
    this.model.on('remove', this.render, this);
//this thing-----------
    this.model.fetch({
      success: function(response){
        _.each(response.toJSON(), function(item) {
          console.log('Successfully GOT todo with _id: '+ item._id);
        });
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log('Failed to get blogs!');
      }
    })
  },
//this thing end-----------
  render: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$el.html('');
    _.each(this.model.toArray(), function(todo) {
      self.$el.append((new TodoView({model: todo})).render().$el);
    });
    return this;
  }
});
```

this.model.fetch is trying to fetch from the url: from up there, but that tutorial was using MongoDB. How do I use parse.com to do the same thing??

It would be awesome if you explained your answers, because I just tried to learn backbone/node/express/parse yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Messages = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model:Message,
  url:'https://api.parse.com/1/something/something',
  getMessages:function() {
    this.fetch({
      data:{
        order:'-createdAt' 
      }
    });
  },

  parse:function(response, options) {
    return response.results.reverse();
  }

});
```

In your example you are fetching and posting to your own computer `http://localhost:3000/api/todos` which I'm guessing you learned from your tutorial. Setup and account with parse.com and checkout out the docks. You will change the url to match their API. Checkout out their REST api documentation for specifics https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide.